# edited outlook reminders not synced to Android device

Tags: sync, calendar, outlook

My work laptops Outlook Calendar is synced with my Android calendar. new appointments show up, and also edited timeslots are updates on my device. But when I remove the alarm to remind me of an event then this removal is not synced to my phone

my phone: HTC Desire HD running Android: 2.3.3